# Query to group 5 records

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table for eg "employee" with just one column "id". Say you have records from 1 through 1000.

```
Employee
------------
ID
------------
1
2
3
..
..
999
1000
```

Now I would like to write a query which gives the following results i.e. sort by ascending order and concatenate first 5 to 1 record, second 5 to 2 second, and so on. Any ideas how I can do this?

Here is the output I am looking to have.

```
 1,2,3,4,5
 6,7,8,9,10
 11,12,13,14,15
 ...........
 ...........
 996,997,998,999,1000
```

Comment: Better to do this type of aggregation at higher level i.e. application code where you can control much more aspects of grouping. You can achieve it using while loop in SQL but it is considered inefficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `row_number` and `listagg` functions, in this way:

```
SELECT listagg( id, ',' ) within group( order by group_no, id )
FROM (
   select id,
          trunc((row_number()  over( order by id ) -1) / 5) as group_no
   from employee
)
GROUP BY group_no
```

Working demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ef526/10

```
| LISTAGG(ID,',')WITHINGROUP(ORDERBYGROUP_NO,ID) |
|------------------------------------------------|
|                                      1,2,3,4,5 |
|                                     6,7,8,9,10 |
|                                 11,12,13,14,15 |
|                                 16,17,18,19,20 |
|                                 21,22,23,24,25 |
|                                 26,27,28,29,30 |
|                                 31,32,33,34,35 |
|                                 36,37,38,39,40 |
|                                 41,42,43,44,45 |
|                                 46,47,48,49,50 |
|                                 51,52,53,54,55 |
|                                 56,57,58,59,60 |
|                                 61,62,63,64,65 |
|                                 66,67,68,69,70 |
|                                 71,72,73,74,75 |
|                                 76,77,78,79,80 |
|                                 81,82,83,84,85 |
|                                 86,87,88,89,90 |
|                                 91,92,93,94,95 |
|                                96,97,98,99,100 |
|                            101,102,103,104,105 |
|                            106,107,108,109,110 |
|                            111,112,113,114,115 |
|                            116,117,118,119,120 |
|                            121,122,123,124,125 |
|                            126,127,128,129,130 |
|                            131,132,133,134,135 |
|                            136,137,138,139,140 |
|                            141,142,143,144,145 |
|                            146,147,148,149,150 |
|                            151,152,153,154,155 |
|                            156,157,158,159,160 |
|                            161,162,163,164,165 |
|                            166,167,168,169,170 |
|                            171,172,173,174,175 |
|                            176,177,178,179,180 |
|                            181,182,183,184,185 |
|                            186,187,188,189,190 |
|                            191,192,193,194,195 |
|                            196,197,198,199,200 |
```